# How to persist Android application data to a Heroku-compatible database?

Tags: android, database, web-applications, heroku, cloud

I'm an aspiring Android application developer looking for a secure way to persist the data on my android application to an online database. I'm interested in using an online database offered by (or at least compatible with) Heroku. This is because I'm also an aspiring web application developer who would like to be able to use the data from my Android application in my web application hosted by Heroku.

Any suggestions on resources (tutorials, books, etc) to help me learn about ways to persist Android application data to the cloud? If there's no good resources on this topic available, maybe you could give me some pointers on how to get started. (I've tried searching for information myself, but what I found has only served to add to the confusion!) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add RESTful web services to your web application and access them from your Android client.

Please, take a look at http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html for best practices of syncing remote data.

If your server is written in Java you can take advantage of Google App Engine integration - http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-app-engine-a-developer-s-dream-combination.html